# How to set numeric round abort in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on enhancing an application and using Microsoft .NET Core Identity for IAM in our application [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore]. 
The database is Microsoft SQL Server. The database setup is pretty much standard except the "NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT" will be turned ON.

But when we start the application we are getting the below exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   'CREATE INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT'.
>   Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type

Working scenarios :

Scenario 1: When the "NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT" is turned OFF in server level, the application works fine and no issues.

Scenario 2: When I extract the table creation queries from the database and execute them with "NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT" turned ON, still everything works.

Scenario 3: When the  "NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT" is turned OFF in server level, and started application first time (letting all the tables created by ef core) and turned ON, next time onwards app works, as the necessary tables and indexes are created already.

Non-working scenario :

When the "NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT" is turned ON in server level, and when we run the application first time, it throws an exception.

I understand the reason that it is expected to get the exception after a loss of precision occurs in an expression and when creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views.

Could you please help me, can we fix this programmatically. Is that possible?

P.S: Changing in the database will not be a possible option[In my case].

Thank you all for your advice and help.

Comment: So we're talking about initial migration for identity here?  If so, what does `dotnet ef migrations script` show and how does it compare with scenario 2?